# Can't use Kotlins value class in JPA Entity

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa

If I use value class

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class TenantId(val id: Long)
```

in entity

```kotlin
@Entity
class Example(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String,
    val tenantId: TenantId? = null,
) {
```

I will get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: TenantId, at table: device, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(tenant_id)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:499) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way around  it?

There's nothing more to add to the question but I need to add some text so that SO stops nagging me about lack of details.

Comment: Which versions of Kotlin and Hibernate are you using (edit: I see you have Hibernate 5.4.32)? I just tried it with Kotlin 1.5 and Hibernate 5.4.28 and it worked out of the box for me.